# Fold clock tables on startup

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file with a few clock tables up front. I would like to see them folded when opening the file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following header to your file:

```
#+STARTUP: hideblocks
```

Your clocktables will be folded at start. This will also fold all your other blocks. You can set this variable globally by customizing `org-hide-block-startup`. I don't think there's a built-in way to fold only your clock tables.

Details are in the manual, [(org) Blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Blocks.html#Blocks)